# Scala List chained cons operators vs List constructor

Tags: scala

Are the two List constructs below equivalent in terms of compilation/memory footprint?

```
val list1 = x1 :: x2 :: x3 :: Nil
val list2 = List(x1, x2, x3)
```

I think `list1` is more costly as each `h :: t` creates a List, which then concatenates each new element (resulting in a new list) until the final list. While `list2` creates a List in one shot.

Comment: Your assumption that `List(x1, x2, x3)` creates the whole thing in one shot false.  You other assumption that building up a List piece by piece is inefficient is also false. `List` is a linked list, which means it is built up by elements connected to each other in a chain.  a `List` object is actually just a single element with a reference tot he next element, so the intermediate lists you are worried about aren't discarded, they are actually a apart of the final list.

Answer (score 8):

I would think, the first one is more efficient: it actually goes right-to left, and prepending an element to a list is actually very cheap, as cheap as creating a new instance of a case class: `def ::(x: T) = new scala.collection.immutable.::(x, this)`

The other way is actually a varargs call, so, it first creates a new array, and puts all variables there, then wraps it into a `Seq`, then does `Seq.toList`, which ends up going through a similar (but more involved/expensive) way of appending elements of that `Seq` to a new list one-by-one.

So, the first way is more efficient, but I doubt the difference is actually going to be detectable in any kind of code you can actually type by hand.